# What happens if the initialized weights for GD is a saddle point?

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, gd

Do the existing weight init strategies guarantee that they would not end up at a saddle point?

Answer (score 0):

The majority of intialization methods today are random intialization. Thus almost certainly the model is not initialized in a saddle point unless the function is constant on an open set. In fact the mesure of the set of saddle points is nulle over the space of parameters, unless the function is constant on an open set.